# jQuery Waiting for Multiple Events to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Is it possible to "wait" for multiple events before executing a function?  I know its possible with `jQuery` `deferred` obejcts to use `$.when` to wait for two promises to resolve but I wondered if its possible with just plain old events?

Lets say a click event and a custom event trigger an alert, for example:

```
$.when("click", "customEvent").then(function(){ alert("yay"); });
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You *could* use deferred, you just have to create them yourself.

```
var clickDfd = $.Deferred();
var eventDfd = $.Deferred();
$("div").on("click", function(e) {
   clickDfd.resolve();
});

$("div").on("some-event", function(e) {
   eventDfd.resolve();
});

$.when(clickDfd, eventDfd).done(function(){ 
    alert("yay"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var click = 0;
var hover = 0;
$("div").on("click mouseenter", function(e) {
   if(e.type == 'click') {
      click = 1;
      bana();
   }
   else if(e.type == 'mouseenter') {
      hover = 1;
      bana();
   }
});
function bana() {
   if(click == 1 && hover == 1) {
       alert(1);
       click = 0;
       hover = 0;
   }
   else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Well, Checking event types and setting them in old way. Plain jQuery and JS.

Will alert 1 only when both events are done / fired.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cCvYm/1/)

Comment: I've considered using this approach (and probably will), I was just curious if their was some sort of neat tidy "magic" jQuery way.  Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @CrimsonChin we just don't sit back to wait for someone to do magic for you. You should search around web or try yourself. Well, in my point of view, I don't think tidy solution always help. You also need dirty solutions if you are well determined to make something big.